# CSS Property not overriding in Angular Project

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

So I found a bootstrap 4 landing page (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/resume/) that I wanted to integrate it into my Angular project https://github.com/mannyliens/my-portfolio-v2/tree/master/my-portfolio-v2. I moved all the files over (except the gulp file and I didn't not include any of the dependencies) and adjusted the links accordingly. I'm trying to update the background color and but while checking the devtools (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbGuw.jpg) I changed every instance of #007bff to a new color (#b22222) but to no avail.

```
.bg-primary {
    background-color: #007bff!important;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure where this is coming from even though I changed all instances in my Angular Project. Any answers or suggestions to what is wrong?

Comment: is inline working?

Comment: @Nihal I'm avoiding inline styling - I prefer for the styling to be inherited through the .css files.

Comment: You are missing a space in your code snippet.

Comment: `#007bff !important`

Comment: Click on the `<style></style>` link in the top-right of the dev tools. It will show you exactly where it's set.

Comment: Just to elaborate I'm trying to avoid overriding the styling by (inline or creating another class) - I prefer to understand why despite manually changing the background color for all instances in my project that it still has not changed the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue to my problem. In my angular-cli.json file, I had  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" defined in my style attribute - which explains why the background color didn't change when I updated all instances of .bg-primary. Since "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" isn't in my src folder these files weren't affected by my original change.

To solve my problem I had to remove all the values defined in my angular-cli.json file under the styling attribute and the update them with the .css filepaths from my assets/vendor folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to force angular to override the styles.

```
::ng-deep .bg-primary {
  background-color: #007bff!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference comes from the bootstrap.min.css that your project is based on(from your .angular-cli.json file).
You can override these by specifying class that override bootstrap stuff.

example from your project instead of `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top" id="sideNav">` you can replace bg-primary with a different class or add the new .css class after such as : navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top newCssClassThatOverrideBGPrimary